# Binary logistic regression

Tags: regression, logistic, binary-data

im new to binary logistic regression. I don't know whether the test is giving me real results based on my data set.

My dependent variable will be the presence of STEC in fecal samples (Presence= Yes, Absence = No) .

I have 9 independent variables:
Season: Winter = 0, summer = 1
Geographic location: Urban = 0, rural = 1
Production systems: Backyard/extensive = 0, Intensive/semi-intensive = 1
Age: <12 months = o, >12 months = 1
lactation: dry cow = 0, lactating cow = 1
Antibiotics treatment: No= 0, Yes = 1
Parity number: no parity= 0, parity number >1 = 1
Feed: Forages = 0, others = 1
Health status: Disease = 0, healthy = 1

Is it possible to include all these predictors? should I use blocks? im a bit confused

Can you help me please?

Comment: part of this answer will depend on how much data you actually have, but in principle yes you can fit nine 2 level factors to a binary response. As for "blocks", do you mean random effects? If you only have two levels for these predictors I would suggest not using them as random effetcs.

Comment: also lol @ dry cow